# Android JDBC connection results in ctahttp exception

Tags: android, mysql, android-studio, jdbc

Im currently trying to establish a connection from my Android app to a MySQL server running on my raspberry pi.

I added the library to android studio correctly by adding it's into the dependencys in the module menu.

I implemented the JDBC-method like this into my program.

```
 public void readDatabase(String query)throws  Exception{

        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");

            connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://192.168.0.101/mydb","user","mypassword");

            statement = connection.createStatement();

            resultSet = statement.executeQuery(query);

            System.out.println(resultSet);

        }catch (ClassNotFoundException e){

            e.printStackTrace();

        }finally {
            close();
        }

    }

    private void close(){
        try {
            if (resultSet != null){
                resultSet.close();
            }

            if (statement != null){
                statement.close();
            }

            if ( connection != null){
                connection.close();
            }
        }catch (Exception e){

        }
    }
```

Every time I fire up the program I get an class not found error. 
It says :

> W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: system/framework/mediatek-cta.jar
>   I/System.out: e:java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mediatek.cta.CtaHttp

I tried to search in different ways for the problem but I can not figure out where the problem is.
I don't even know what the cta  class is. Maybe someone can help me out here.

Comment: any safe method to resolve this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**CTA  = China Type Approval**, this is something that Mediatek adds in Android for testing purpose.

Your error is happening in *DriverManager.getConnection()* that probably uses *okhttp*, *apache-http* or *Socket* class in Android's *libcore* to do its requests.

Mediatek patched these libraries for adding a control of HTTP requests. It tries to load dynamically some methods defined in */system/framework/mediatek-cta.jar* but it is probably absent or not accessible on your android device's file system.

I see 5 solutions :

1. **Add an appropriate mediatek-cta.jar** via OTA or via adb remount if you are on a custom/rooted ROM
2. Use **another device** with the same application's source code (a non- Mediatek based device would not have that issue).
3. **Upgrading your OS** via an official OTA update and hope device manufacturer fixed the issue.
4. **Rebuild and customize the OS by yourself** with the following modifications

   - Make sure medatek-cta is added to *PRODUCT_PACKAGES* and *PRODUCT_BOOT_JARS*
   - Remove the hooks in libcore, okhttp and apache-http.
5. **Contact** your OS maintainer's **support**.

Answer (score 1):

As I encountered the same message once, I also was misled by it firstly.
However, it turned out that you can not open a Socket or other network connection on the main thread (see https://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/connecting#intro-net-ops). This may also be the problem in your case.

This message itself only seems to be an information for testing purposes as vhamon pointed out.

Answer (score 1):

add this permisions to AndroidManifest, hope will help)

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>`

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />`

Comment: I added both of these permissions to AndroidManifest.xml and it did not help: I am still getting `ClassLoader referenced unknown path: system/framework/mediatek-cta.jar`