# How to connect flask scoketIO to my flutter chat APP

Tags: flutter, flask-socketio, flask-sockets

How to connect my flutter app to flask_socketIO python ? In flutter i am making a  chat APP whose backend to fetch the users is in flask bakcend. So how should i connect both of them ?

Answer (score 0):

you can use this package [flutter_socket_io](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_socket_io)

Initialize your socket io server

```
SocketIO socketIO = SocketIOManager()
                      .createSocketIO("http://127.0.0.1:3000", 
                      "/chat", 
                      query: "userId=21031", 
                      socketStatusCallback: _socketStatus);
```

Initialization and subscription to your socket backend

```
socketIO.init(); 
socketIO.subscribe("socket_info", _onSocketInfo); 
socketIO.connect();
```

Add a callback function to listen for any new information coming in and do whatever u want with the data

```
_socketStatus(dynamic data) { 
    //do whatever
    print("Socket status: " + data); 
}
```

Comment: java.lang.classnotfoundexception com.mediatek.cta.ctahttp Yes Bro I have connected but Now i am getting this error in my debug console

Comment: please try to look at this thread to fix (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54621628/android-jdbc-connection-results-in-ctahttp-exception)