# Problems with transferring data over sockets

Tags: java, android, sockets

I decided to learn network programming in Java, and started with sockets. To start, I decided to create an Android chat client in which you can chat in real time, data is transmitted via sockets. To understand the principle, at first I simply rewrote the code for the simplest client-server connection. However, when trying to connect to the server (Android device - client, computer - server), a ClassNotFoundException is thrown:

```
I/System.out: [socket]:check permission begin!
W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: system/framework/mediatek-cta.jar
I/System.out: [socket] e:java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mediatek.cta.CtaUtils
```

I got permission to connect to the Internet in the manifest, I create a connection in a separate thread.

Client code:

```
try {
    InetAddress addr = InetAddress.getByName("26.242.96.221");
    Socket socket = new Socket(addr, 8080);

    System.out.println("socket = " + socket);
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(
                        new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())), true);
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            out.println("howdy " + i);
            String str = in.readLine();
            System.out.println(str);
        }
        out.println("END");
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Server code:

```
public class Server {
    public static final int PORT = 8080;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ServerSocket s = new ServerSocket(PORT);
        System.out.println("Started: " + s);
        try {
            Socket socket = s.accept();
            try {
                System.out.println("Connection accepted: " + socket);
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                        socket.getInputStream()));

                PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(
                        new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())), true);
                while (true) {
                    String str = in.readLine();
                    if (str.equals("END"))
                        break;
                    System.out.println("Echoing: " + str);
                    out.println(str);
                }
            }
            finally {
                System.out.println("closing...");
                socket.close();
            }
        }
        finally {
            s.close();
        }
    }
}
```

I found this answer:

> Mediatek patched these libraries for adding a control of HTTP requests. It tries to load dynamically some methods defined in /system/framework/mediatek-cta.jar but it is probably absent or not accessible on your android device's file system.

Can't my device work with sockets because of this? If not, how else can you transfer data between devices (text, music, online broadcasts)? I would be grateful for the answer

(I translated it with google translate, sorry for my English)

Comment: Do away with getByName() and start your socket with new Socket('26.242.96.221"   , 8080); That ip is of...? Is it a local ip?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54985015/10871900

Comment: Which statement causes the class not found exception? Of course you can use sockets in in your android apps.

Comment: @blackapps, This is the ip of the computer that I access from the Android device

Comment: @blackapps, These exceptions are caused by the Android system itself.

Comment: ?? If it has nothing to do with your code.. then i do not understand what is happening. You should clarify. Starting with telling when this exception occurs.

Answer (score 3):

Everything turned out to be terribly simple: the fact is that I connected to a server (computer), which accessed the Internet via Wi-Fi, using a mobile network on my Android device, nothing happened. But when I connected the phone to the Wi-Fi network, everything worked. How I figured it out

```
I / System.out: [socket]: check permission begin!
W / System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: system / framework / mediatek-cta.jar
I / System.out: [socket] e: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mediatek.cta.CtaUtils
```

not an error, but a warning related to the fact that Mediatek on Android is trying to find a class, but it is not in the device's file system. And this does not affect the work. It remains to understand how to connect to a computer through any connection