# how to install a file jar via tha adb console

Tags: java, android, visual-studio, xamarin

I have this ClassNotFoundException

> [System.out] [okhttp] e:java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mediatek.cta.CtaUtils

So I'm trying to download the mediatek-cta.jar class, the question is how to do that via the adb console in visual studio.

Comment: Thank you for supporting xamarin android, are you sure you do not want to try the nuget package manager console?

Comment: Yes I tryed it before but I don't know if I can download this class from it

Comment: This link explains the binding of a jar file to a Xamarin android project https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/binding-java-library/binding-a-jar

Comment: you need to generate a dll from the Jar file and then add the dll as a reference to your project. That is after creating a new Xamarin Binding project and then set the build action to Embedded Jar and then point the build target to your jar file and then generate a dll form that

Comment: I didn't have the mediatek-cta.jar class I thought that it can be installed automatically

Comment: Am sorry, you currently do not have access to the jar file?

Comment: yes I can't access because it's doesn't exist

Comment: Is it a networking library and is there any particular reason as to why you must use the jar file?

Comment: I'm consuming a post asp.net web api in xamarin and that's the exception cause I didn't even know what kind of library is

Comment: You are right and it looks like your not the only one facing the issue, it was an issue opened up on Github, check out the discussion https://github.com/amitshekhariitbhu/Fast-Android-Networking/issues/467

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65213723/problems-with-transferring-data-over-sockets

Comment: Try running the post on wifi and not mobile network according to the post I linked above

Comment: @TechGeek No I need to running it in a physical device because it's a final project I will show the application to the professor. should I maybe redownload visual studio?

Comment: no Visual Studio is completely innocent of that