# Android receive messages from socket in python server

Tags: java, python, android, sockets

I'm trying to get messages from python server after I send messages with this code

I made the code on Android so that every time I click the button, this code will be activated and connected from a new client and the Python will send the message back to all participants who have ever logged in to send to the new client as well

How can I also receive messages from the server?

My code:

```
class Send extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {
    public Socket socket; // Create socket
    public PrintWriter printWriter; // Create print writer

    protected Void doInBackground(String... strings) {
        String command = strings[0]; // Set the command

        try {
            socket = new Socket("10.0.0.2", 13131); // Set socket connection
            printWriter = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream()); // Set the print writer with socket properties

            printWriter.write(command); // Send the command to server
            printWriter.flush(); // Clear the line
            

            socket.close();
            
        }
        catch (UnknownHostException e) {e.printStackTrace();} // Error exception
        catch (IOException e) {e.printStackTrace();} // Error exception

        return null;
    }
}
```

I tried with

```
        InputStream input = socket.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));
        String line = reader.readLine();

        System.out.println(line);
```

And I got an error exception:

```
I/System.out: [socket] e:java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mediatek.cta.CtaUtils
```

**How can I receive the messages?**

My python server:

```
    server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) # Set the socket
    server.bind((socket.gethostname(), 13131)) # Set socket properties

    server.listen()
    (client, (ipNum, portNum)) = server.accept() # Accept to new client

    print("Phone connected")

    while True:
        server.listen()
        (client, (ipNum, portNum)) = server.accept() # Accept to new clients (Accept to new command from the phone)

        Clients.append(client)

        message = str(client.recv(32).decode()) # Set the command as string

        if(message != ""): # Checks if a command has been sent
            print("Client: " + message) # Print the command

            Command(message.lower()) # Process the command

            for Client in Clients:
                Client.send(str(BackMessage).encode())
                Clients.remove(Client)

            print("Server: " + BackMessage) # Print the BackMessage


        else:
            for Client in Clients:
                Client.send(str(BackMessage).encode())
                Clients.remove(Client)

            time.sleep(0.05) # Sleep for 0.05 seconds
```

Comment: The original error message said you needed an encoding; so add one.

Comment: Do you have to convert to string?  Can you just do `bytes(x)`?

Comment: It send b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'

Comment: If I write ```bytes(x)```

Comment: Have you decided what you want to send? Do you want to send the "letters" 1234 like you typed them on the keyboard?

Comment: But I want to add 1 every time. I can't do that with string. I need integer first to add 1, and than send it

Comment: There are many, many ways to send an integer over a socket. But you must chose a way that is compatible with what your peer expects.

Comment: Please add the whole stacktrace. With the whole log we can be able to know what is happening. ClassNotFoundException can have millions of reasons why it is not found.

Comment: Stop using `AsyncTask`.

Comment: @ZivSion can you add full stack trace

Answer (score 0):

**CTA  = China Type Approval**, this is something that Mediatek adds in Android for testing purpose.

Your error is happening in *DriverManager.getConnection()* that probably uses *okhttp*, *apache-http* or *Socket* class in Android's *libcore* to do its requests.

Mediatek patched these libraries for adding a control of HTTP requests. It tries to load dynamically some methods defined in */system/framework/mediatek-cta.jar* but it is probably absent or not accessible on your android device's file system.

I see 5 solutions :

1. **Add an appropriate mediatek-cta.jar** via OTA or via adb remount if you are on a custom/rooted ROM
2. Use **another device** with the same application's source code (a non- Mediatek based device would not have that issue).
3. **Upgrading your OS** via an official OTA update and hope device manufacturer fixed the issue.
4. **Rebuild and customize the OS by yourself** with the following modifications

- Make sure medatek-cta is added to *PRODUCT_PACKAGES* and *PRODUCT_BOOT_JARS*
- Remove the hooks in libcore, okhttp and apache-http.

5. **Contact** your OS maintainer's **support**.

if its not able able fix by 1 , Out of rest Second one seems to be Easy Solution. Since its OS and hardware related issue.

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54985015/9416473